# Python POST request with requests library

Tags: python, post, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some data from https://www.desaldata.com/cost_estimator by submitting a form (CALCULATE CAPEX button).

To get the information on the post request, I used Chrome's developer tool (network tab) to get the information when I submit the form manually in the browser.

```
Request URL: https://www.desaldata.com/cost_estimator.json
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

The following is the form data

```
utf8: ✓
[technology]: swro
capacity: 200000
[seawater]: 0
[seawater_min_temp]: 0
[seawater_max_temp]: 0
[med_or_msf_pretreatment]: 0
[pretreatment]: 0
[second_pass]: 0
[remineralization]: 0
[intake_outfall]: 0
[permitting]: 0
[country_factor]: 
annual_production: 69,350,000
utilisation_rate: 95
energy_consumption: 3.5
energy_price: 0.08
[labour_factor]: 1
interest_rate: 6
equity_yield: 12
loan_repayment_timescale: 20
debt_equity_split: 75
commit: Calculate Capex
cost_estimator.json
```

Here is my code.

```
import requests

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
request_url = "https://www.desaldata.com/cost_estimator.json"
data = {'[technology]': 'swro', 'capacity': 200000, '[seawater]': 0, '[seawater_min_temp]': 0, '[seawater_max_temp]': 0,'[med_or_msf_pretreatment]': 0, '[pretreatment]': 0, '[second_pass]': 0, '[remineralization]': 0, '[intake_outfall]': 0, '[permitting]': 0, 'annual_production': 69350000, 'utilisation_rate': 95, 'energy_consumption': 3.5, 'energy_price': 0.08, '[labour_factor]': 1, 'interest_rate': 6, 'equity_yield': 12, 'loan_repayment_timescale': 20, 'debt_equity_split': 75, 'commit': 'Calculate Capex'}

r = requests.post(request_url, headers = headers, data = data)
```

I am getting 400 response. I am not sure how to send utf8: ✓ and [country_factor]:  which does not have a value. How should I fix my code?

Comment: Does setting `headers = {'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}` and `'[country_factor]': None` help?

Comment: No, I still get 400 response with those changes.